# Is there a good Cheat Sheet for the "ps" command?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

I know the question was already asked in some way, but I'd like to find a good Cheat Sheet especially for the "ps" command. I've never been able to memorize the useful options, mostly because I use "top" or "htop" on a daily basis, but "ps" is still very useful in many cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I use `man` and `info` as cheatsheets

Comment: Seems there is only this one left :P

Comment: If that's the case, with all due respect, you don't know what cheat sheet is :P

Answer (score 0):

The man page is actually pretty good.  The main thing is to read the section about the BSD vs UNIX options.

The examples right at the top act as a cheat sheet for common uses. Also, the 'STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS' section is also good for just getting the output you want.

Comment: man page link - http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's any detail on the **ps** command, but there are some good linux **cheat-sheets** at http://monsterb.org/cheat-sheets.html